# Dificuldade em implementar criptografia de senha com Spring Boot

Tags: criptografia, spring-boot, spring-security

Pelo titulo vocês podem perceber que é um projeto Spring Boot, e sendo um projeto Spring Boot muitas coisas já vem configuradas pelo FrameWorks, mas não sei em relação a implementação de criptografia de senha, em Spring MVC tem que configurar algumas coisas na mão, mas vamos lá....

me parece que fiz tudo certo... mas mesmo assim está gerando mensagem de erro, a mensagem de erro vou mostrar no final dessa postagem.

Como o projeto é um pouco grande vou mostrar o passo á passo do que fiz para implementar criptografia de senha.

1º Eu incluir as biblioteca, eu não sei se essa biblioteca e a versão está correta.

```
    <properties>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <spring-security-web.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring-security-web.version>

</properties>
```

e no final ....

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security-web.version}</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/pom.xml

2º Depois eu crio uma classe para exceção

```
public class SenhaObrigatoriaUsuarioException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SenhaObrigatoriaUsuarioException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/controller/service/exception/SenhaObrigatoriaUsuarioException.java

3º Na classe de serviços incluo essa linhas de código

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

mais esse...

```
if (usuario.isNovo() && StringUtils.isEmpty(usuario.getSenha())) {
            throw new SenhaObrigatoriaUsuarioException("Senha é obrigatória para novo usuário");
        }

        if (usuario.isNovo()) {
            usuario.setSenha(this.passwordEncoder.encode(usuario.getSenha()));
            usuario.setConfirmacaoSenha(usuario.getSenha());
        }
```

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/controller/service/CadastroUsuarioService.java

4º E em seguida configuro a segurança para tudo funcionar..

```
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/config/SecurityConfig.java

5º coloco a implementação a exceção no controller

```
catch (SenhaObrigatoriaUsuarioException e) {
    result.rejectValue("senha", e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
    return novo(usuario);
}
```

https://github.com/wladyband/arm/blob/master/arm/src/main/java/br/com/arm/controller/UsuarioController.java

Mas mesmo assim gerou um erro como podem ver a baixo;

```
2017-07-04T12:45:14.833372+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-07-04 12:45:14.832  INFO 4 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :
2017-07-04T12:45:14.833375+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-07-04T12:45:14.833376+00:00 app[web.1]: Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled
.
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846044+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-07-04 12:45:14.845 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup fai
led
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846047+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846048+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defin
ed in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method fa
iled; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterCha
in' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/session/SessionInformationExpiredStrategy
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846049+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.ja
va:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846051+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(Abstrac
tAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846054+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCa
pableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846055+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableB
eanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBea
nFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846057+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-b
eans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.j
ava:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846058+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846059+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans
-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846060+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-bea
ns-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846061+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans
-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846061+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanF
actory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846062+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplication
Context.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846063+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spri
ng-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846064+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java
:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846065+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.
5.3.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846066+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.j
ar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846066+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.
RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846067+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3
.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846068+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3
.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846069+00:00 app[web.1]:    at br.com.arm.ArmApplication.main(ArmApplication.java:15) [classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846074+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846075+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846076+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846077+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846077+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPS
HOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846078+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846079+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846079+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [arm-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846081+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory m
ethod 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/session/SessionInformationExp
iredStrategy
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846081+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java
:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846082+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.ja
va:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846083+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 28 common frames omitted
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846084+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/session/SessionInformationExpiredStrategy
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846084+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.sessionManagement(HttpSecurity.java:399)
~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846085+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityC
onfigurerAdapter.java:208) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846086+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConf
igurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846101+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConf
igurerAdapter.java:86) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846101+00:00 app[web.1]:    at br.com.arm.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb73af8b.init(<generated>) ~[classes!/:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846102+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBu
ilder.java:371) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846103+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurit
yBuilder.java:325) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846103+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[sp
ring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846105+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChai
n(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846108+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$
5cbaee68.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$4(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846109+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$
5cbaee68$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$72103c9a.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846110+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.
3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846114+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationCla
ssEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846115+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$
5cbaee68.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>) ~[spring-security-config-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.2.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846116+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846117+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846118+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846118+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846119+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java
:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846120+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 29 common frames omitted
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846120+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionInformationExpiredStrategy
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846121+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846122+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[arm-1.0.0-SNAPS
HOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846122+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846123+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_121-heroku16]
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846124+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 48 common frames omitted
2017-07-04T12:45:14.846125+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-07-04T12:45:14.976913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-07-04T12:45:14.969705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-07-04T12:45:43.368255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/login" host=wb-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com request_id=70fd7aae
-424b-4fd8-9d90-63f36cabe239 fwd="177.223.27.17" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**O que será que está havendo?**

É um projeto que está no servidor Heroku.
Pra ter uma ideia o servidor não conseguir nem subir a pagina web.
Se eu tirar todas as configurações do passo á passo da implementação de criptografia o projeto volta a funcionar sem erros, eu acho que o problema é configuração do próprio projeto Spring Boot, deve está faltando alguma coisa.

Comment: Tente utilizar a mesma versão para o spring security, não informando spring-security-web.version.